# How to give paged links custom title?

Tags: pages, navigation

I have split my post content into mutiple pages using the  `<! - nextpage ->` code. I want to give my paginated links their own title instead of the regular 1,2,3. How can I do this? cause on this doc https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links it only mentions method to adding suffix or prefix. I just want to give each paged number their own custom title

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a way to support pagination titles of the form:

```
<!--nextpage(.*?)?-->
```

in a simlar way as the core supports `<!--more(.*?)?-->`.

Here's an example:

```
<!--nextpage Planets -->
Let's talk about the Planets
<!--nextpage Mercury -->
Exotic Mercury
<!--nextpage Venus-->
Beautiful Venus
<!--nextpage Earth -->
Our Blue Earth
<!--nextpage Mars -->
The Red Planet
```

with the output similar to:

[image: Pagination titles]

This was tested on the *Twenty Sixteen* theme, where I had to adjust the *padding* and *width* a little bit:

```
.page-links a, .page-links > span {
    width:   auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

### Demo plugin

Here's a demo plugin that uses the `content_pagination`, `wp_link_pages_link`, `pre_handle_404` and `wp_link_pages_args` filters to support this extenstion of the *nextpage* marker (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Content Pagination Titles
 * Description: Support for &lt;!--nextpage(.*?)?--&gt; in the post content
 * Version:     1.0.1
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/227022/26350
 */

namespace WPSE\Question202709;

add_action( 'init', function()
{
    $main = new Main;
    $main->init();
} );

class Main
{
    private $pagination_titles;

    public function init()
    {
        add_filter( 'pre_handle_404',       [ $this, 'pre_handle_404' ],        10, 2       );
        add_filter( 'content_pagination',   [ $this, 'content_pagination' ],    -1, 2       );
        add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link',   [ $this, 'wp_link_pages_link' ],    10, 2       );
        add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_args',   [ $this, 'wp_link_pages_args' ],    PHP_INT_MAX );
    }

    public function content_pagination( $pages, $post )
    {
        // Empty content pagination titles for each run
        $this->pagination_titles = [];

        // Nothing to do if the post content doesn't contain pagination titles
        if( false === stripos( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage' ) )
            return $pages;

        // Collect pagination titles
        preg_match_all( '/<!--nextpage(.*?)?-->/i', $post->post_content, $matches );
        if( isset( $matches[1] ) )
            $this->pagination_titles = $matches[1];     

        // Override $pages according to our new extended nextpage support
        $pages = preg_split( '/<!--nextpage(.*?)?-->/i', $post->post_content );

        // nextpage marker at the top
        if( isset( $pages[0] ) && '' == trim( $pages[0] ) )
        {
            // remove the empty page
            array_shift( $pages );
        }       
        // nextpage marker not at the top
        else
        {
            // add the first numeric pagination title 
            array_unshift( $this->pagination_titles, '1' );
        }           
        return $pages;
    }

    public function wp_link_pages_link( $link, $i )
    {
        if( ! empty( $this->pagination_titles ) )
        {
            $from  = '{{TITLE}}';
            $to    = ! empty( $this->pagination_titles[$i-1] ) ? $this->pagination_titles[$i-1] : $i;
            $link  = str_replace( $from, $to, $link );
        }

        return $link;
    }

    public function wp_link_pages_args( $params )
    {       
        if( ! empty( $this->pagination_titles ) )
        {
            $params['next_or_number'] = 'number';
            $params['pagelink'] = str_replace( '%', '{{TITLE}}', $params['pagelink'] );
        }
        return $params;
    }

    /**
     * Based on the nextpage check in WP::handle_404()
     */
    public function pre_handle_404( $bool, \WP_Query $q )
    {
        global $wp;

        if( $q->posts && is_singular() )
        {
            if ( $q->post instanceof \WP_Post ) 
                $p = clone $q->post;

            // check for paged content that exceeds the max number of pages
            $next = '<!--nextpage';
            if (   $p 
                 && false !== stripos( $p->post_content, $next ) 
                 && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['page'] ) 
            ) {
                $page = trim( $wp->query_vars['page'], '/' );
                $success = (int) $page <= ( substr_count( $p->post_content, $next ) + 1 );

                if ( $success )
                {
                    status_header( 200 );
                    $bool = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $bool;
    }

} // end class
```

*Installation*: Create the `/wp-content/plugins/content-pagination-titles/content-pagination-titles.php` file and activate the plugin. Always a good idea to backup before testing any plugin.

If the top *nextpage* marker is missing, then the first pagination title is numeric.

Also if a content pagination title is missing, i.e. `<!--nextpage-->`, then it will be numeric, just as expected.

I first forgot about the *nextpage* bug in the `WP` class, that shows up if we modify the number of pages via the `content_pagination` filter. This was recently reported by @PieterGoosen here in [#35562](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35562).

We try to overcome that in our demo plugin with a `pre_handle_404` filter callback, based on the `WP` class check [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0016e4bb122a8da9b70d2703f805ba5a9821eadd/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L652-680),  where we check for `<!--nextpage` instead of `<!--nextpage-->`.

### Tests

Here are some further tests:

**Test #1**

```
<!--nextpage-->
Let's talk about the Planets
<!--nextpage-->
Exotic Mercury
<!--nextpage-->
Beautiful Venus
<!--nextpage-->
Our Blue Earth
<!--nextpage-->
The Red Planet
```

Output for *1* selected:

[image: test1]

as expected.

**Test #2**

```
Let's talk about the Planets
<!--nextpage-->
Exotic Mercury
<!--nextpage-->
Beautiful Venus
<!--nextpage-->
Our Blue Earth
<!--nextpage-->
The Red Planet
```

Output for *5* selected:

[image: test2]

as expected.

**Test #3**

```
<!--nextpage-->
Let's talk about the Planets
<!--nextpage Mercury-->
Exotic Mercury
<!--nextpage-->
Beautiful Venus
<!--nextpage Earth -->
Our Blue Earth
<!--nextpage Mars -->
The Red Planet
```

Output for *3* selected:

[image: test3]

as expected.

**Test #4**

```
Let's talk about the Planets
<!--nextpage Mercury-->
Exotic Mercury
<!--nextpage Venus-->
Beautiful Venus
<!--nextpage Earth -->
Our Blue Earth
<!--nextpage Mars -->
The Red Planet
```

Output with *Earth* selected:

[image: test4]

as expected.

### Alternatives

Another way would be to modify it to support pagination titles to be added with:

```
<!--pt Earth-->
```

It might also be handy to support a single comment for all pagination titles (*pts*):

```
<!--pts Planets|Mercury|Venus|Earth|Mars -->
```

or perhaps via custom fields?

Comment: This looks interesting and quite dynamic. ;-)

Comment: +1 for closure technique ;) Before that I only knew that we are limited to `apply_filter` arguments :D

Comment: It can be handy when writing short code snippets here on WPSE, but we could also just write a class to support this in a proper plugin ;-) @Sumit

Comment: @PieterGoosen I first forgot about the [#35562](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35562) bug, tried to adjust it via the `pre_handle_404` filter.

Comment: @birgire I thought of that issue, but could not test anything to confirm or disregard the influence of that issue, I''m so caught up with other projects which does not require a pc. It seems like the bug will remain for a long time. I previously did test on new and old versions, and my conclusions is that the code causing the bug can be removed from core until someone finds a proper solution... ;-)

Comment: @birgire on my custom theme it shows the page titles duplicated like for example: Page: Planets Planets, Mercury Mercury, Venus Venus. Is there a template tag that I must include to get rid of the duplicate titles? cause I notice on some themes it doesn't show duplicates while some others do so I think there may be a template or function that I need to add to my custom theme

Comment: I tested this on the TwentySixteen theme if I recall correctly. It's hard to say about custom themes without testing it. Do you have a link to a downloadable public theme that I can test, where this duplication shows? @Ruriko

Comment: @birgire I'm using Naked Wordpress https://github.com/j-beckman/naked-wordpress/archive/master.zip The duplicates appear when using <?php wp_link_pages(); ?> tag

Comment: I updated the answer, it should be more general now. The previous version was constructed with the TwentySixteen theme in mind. @Ruriko

Comment: I'm years late to this, but I've modified parts of this to work in my use case.However, the links say 'Page TITLE' for each one. How do i remove the word Page on these?

Comment: I wonder if you mean adding `$params['before'] = '';` into the `wp_link_pages_args` method above.

Answer (score 5):

You can use filter [`wp_link_pages_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_pages_link/)

First pass our custom string placeholder (This can be anything you like except string containing `%`, just for now I am using `#custom_title#`).

```
wp_link_pages( array( 'pagelink' => '#custom_title#' ) );
```

Then add our filter in `functions.php`. In callback function make an array of titles then check for the current page number and replace `#custom_title#` with value corresponding to current page number.

Example:-

```
add_filter('wp_link_pages_link', 'wp_link_pages_link_custom_title', 10, 2);
/**
 * Replace placeholder with custom titles
 * @param string $link Page link HTML
 * @param int $i Current page number
 * @return string $link Page link HTML
 */
function wp_link_pages_link_custom_title($link, $i) {

    //Define array of custom titles
    $custom_titles = array(
        __('Custom title A', 'text-domain'),
        __('Custom title B', 'text-domain'),
        __('Custom title C', 'text-domain'),
    );

    //Default title when title is not set in array
    $default_title = __('Page', 'text-domain') . ' ' . $i; 

    $i--; //Decrease the value by 1 because our array start with 0

    if (isset($custom_titles[$i])) { //Check if title exist in array if yes then replace it
        $link = str_replace('#custom_title#', $custom_titles[$i], $link);
    } else { //Replace with default title
        $link = str_replace('#custom_title#', $default_title, $link);
    }

    return $link;
}
```